# Tiny fonts in window titles (kubuntu 18.04)

Tags: kubuntu, fonts

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04. The titles of my application windows have tiny, unreadable fonts. The font menu in System Settings controls the fonts in the applications, but not   these.  There's another setting somewhere that controls the window titles and a bunch of other labels -- basically, the meta-information of the screen.

I encountered this problem a long time ago, but I don't remember how I solved it.  Something to do with Gnome settings, I think. I seem to remember that there was some way to fix that in System Settings,but it's not obvious.

Answer (score 0):

In **System Settings/Fonts** there are six contexts listed, and Window Title is one of them.